# How to use `not in` query in Core Data iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios7, xcode5

I am using core data in my app. There is a condition where we check whether a particular key value pair if available should not be deleted like,

```
select * from table where name not in {"abc","pqr","xyz","lmn"};
```

Let's say in table I have names `"abc","pqr","xyz","lmn","mno","efg",` so it should return me only two names "mno" and "efg". but it is returning me all the records available. It is not excluding any available record.
For Core data, I'm setting Predicate like

```
NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:"abc","pqr","xyz","lmn",nil];
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Not(issue_accession IN %@)", array ];
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try not capitalizing the "not" i.e. `@"not(issue_accession IN %@)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. It should not even compile.

In Objective-C strings are written like this: `@"abc"`. You need the `@` sign. I would also rewrite the predicate as below:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not (issue_accession IN %@)",
  @[@"abc",@"pqr",@"xyz",@"lmn"]];
```